# Thirring Model effective potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, effective-field-theory

I have the lagrangian for the Thirring model coupled with vector interaction $V^\mu$ in the large-$N$ approximation:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}=\bar{\psi}\left(i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m - \gamma_\mu V^\mu \right) \psi- \frac{2N_f}{g^2} V^2
\end{equation}

By integrating over the $N_f$ independent fermionic degrees of freedom, it simplifies to:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Z}=\int \mathcal{D}V^\mu  \operatorname{Det}\left(i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m - \gamma_\mu V^\mu\right)^{N_f} \exp \left[-i\int \mathrm{d}^D x \frac{2N_f}{g^2}V^2\right]
\end{equation}

Thus, the effective potential for this model is:

\begin{equation}
V_{\text {eff }}[V^\mu] = \frac{2N_f}{g^2}V^2 + i N_f \operatorname{Tr} \ln \left(i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m - \gamma_\mu V^\mu\right)
\end{equation}

If I consider $V^\mu$ constant and homogeneous, the fermionic determinant of the Thirring model is:

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{det}\left(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m - \gamma_\mu V^\mu\right) = \operatorname{det}\left(-p^2 +V^2 + m^2\right)^2
\tag{1}\end{equation}

I cannot simplify this determinant to obtain the final effective potential, as in this article: "*Symmetries of Thirring models on 3d lattices* by Andreas W. Wipf":

[image: Image from the paper]

What the authors mean is that the final result is:

\begin{equation}
V_{\text {eff }}[V^\mu] = \frac{2N_f}{g^2}V^2 + 2i N_f N_c \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \ln \left(-p^2+m^2\right)
\end{equation}

But I don't understand how the $V^\mu$ disappears inside the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your equation (1), instead of having $-p^2 + V^2 + m^2$, you have $-(p-V)^2 + m^2$. you can then redefine the integration variable $p$ to $p -V$. Since the integration measure doesn't change (as you're only shifting by constant) you have the desired result.

Comment: You are totally correct. Many thanks to answer my question! I appreciate a lot!

Comment: No problem at all!